# CocoaPods libraries errors building for some iOS simulators

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Short error:

```
file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
```

Expanded:
For some simulators, I receive these errors when building my project:

> ld: warning: ignoring file
>   /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ekwldvjyuxwkykbareyvvydbtero/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libFSCalendar.a,
>   file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked
>   (i386):
>   /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ekwldvjyuxwkykbareyvvydbtero/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libFSCalendar.a
>   ld: warning: ignoring file
>   /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ekwldvjyuxwkykbareyvvydbtero/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGBDeviceInfo.a,
>   file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked
>   (i386):
>   /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ekwldvjyuxwkykbareyvvydbtero/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGBDeviceInfo.a
>   ld: warning: ignoring file
>   /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ekwldvjyuxwkykbareyvvydbtero/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libSCLAlertView-Objective-C.a,
>   file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked
>   (i386):
>   /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ekwldvjyuxwkykbareyvvydbtero/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libSCLAlertView-Objective-C.a
>   ld: warning: ignoring file
>   /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ekwldvjyuxwkykbareyvvydbtero/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libSSKeychain.a,
>   file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked
>   (i386):
>   /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ekwldvjyuxwkykbareyvvydbtero/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libSSKeychain.a
>   Undefined symbols for architecture i386:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FSCalendar",
>   referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in VCalendarView.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GBDeviceInfo", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in VEMailView.o
>         objc-class-ref in DataClass.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SCLAlertView", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in VAlerts.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SCLAlertViewBuilder", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in VAlerts.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SCLAlertViewShowBuilder", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in VAlerts.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SSKeychain", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in VDescriptionView.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
>   (use -v to see invocation)

It works for, say, iPhone 6 Plus simulator 9.3.0 but not for iPhone 5s. Why? I have got `$(inherited)` for the **Other Linker Flags** option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I removed the directory
`/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ekwldvjyuxwkykbareyvvydbtero/Build` (right click on the library of CocoaPods > Show in Finder, then find its parent directory) and rebuild all again. Xcode recreated all libraries which works right now. All build preferences are the same as default.

Comment: Alas, this didn't solve it for me.  I quit Xcode, deleted the build directory, relaunched Xcode with the workspace, and hit Run (for simulator) on the main project, and I get exactly the same errors.

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by deleting the `DerivedData` directory.

Steps:

1. In Xcode, go to *Menu bar* → *Window* → *Projects*.
2. In the *Projects* window, choose the project on the left.
3. Click the *Delete...* button for *Derived Data*. When asked to confirm, click *Delete*.
4. Rebuild the project.

---

For Xcode 8, see this Q & A:
[How to delete derived data in Xcode 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38016143)

Comment: My Window menu doesn't have a Projects command (Xcode 8.2.1).  Any idea where to find this in the latest Xcode?